# How to describe the structure of cycles in a directed graph? What are the standard measures for that?

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say we have an unweighted non-planar directed graph with some cycles in it. What are some metrics that would describe the complexity of this "cyclicity" within it? Are there any measures that would be low for both one giant cycle (left extreme) and fully connected graph (right extreme), but would peak in the middle, when you have several cycles arranged in a curious structure?

Upon some research I have found some interesting measures, including the [Cycle Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_rank) measure, and the [Entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_(graph_measure)), but both of them seem to be monotonously increasing as the graph approaches a fully connected graph, while from a structure / information point of view a fully connected graph is as uninteresting as a fully unconnected graph. So I was wondering whether there are any known measures of cyclic structure that characterize how non-random the cycles are. Or whether such measures can be easily created.

Conceivably I could compare the cycle rank of my graph with that of its inverse, but I'm afraid it could be prohibitively computationally expensive, as my graphs are usually rather delicate and openwork, with several longish cycles forming a knot (the graphs come from neuroscience data). It would make the inverse graph too dense and close to a fully connected graph.

It also feels that one could conceivably move to the space to all cycles of length above L, look at probabilities of two cycles having N common nodes, and then calculate the entropy of this distribution, or maybe compare it to a similar distribution in a reshuffled graph, or something like that. But it sounds like something people might have studied extensively before. What do you think? Are there existing techniques that would describe probabilities of cycles in a graph partially overlapping?

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly a better fit at the [computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Either computer science or mathematics.